# How to use key events in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I am having trouble getting my ahk script to work. I want the program to send the letter e when I am pressing Ctrl+1.

Thanks for your help.

I have already tried some variants of the code below.

```
:*:<^Control::+1::e
```

What I am expecting it to do is typing out the letter e but it is doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  ^1::Send, e
  return
```